# How to get a div to follow mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here is a link to what I am trying to achieve: [semplice](http://www.semplicelabs.com/get-semplice)
When hovering over the plans the box follows the mouse. I am trying to recreate the same thing.

This is what I have so far, this is a small demo and I know it isn't anywhere close to how it looks like on the actual website:

html:

```
<div class="centerdiv">
<div class="container">
<div id="follow"></div>
</div></div>
```

css:

```
#follow{
position : relative;
background-color : grey;
width:75px;
height:150px;
}

.centerdiv {
width:150px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
}
.container
{
width:150px;
height:150px;   
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

js:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$('.container').mousemove(function(e){
$("#follow").show();
var offset = $('.container').offset();
console.log(e);
mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

$('.container').mouseleave(function() {
$("#follow").hide(); 
});    


var follow = $("#follow");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 5;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 5;
follow.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8htt9kr/)

Please someone guid me in the right direction

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's not vertical move at the example page, at first you should drop everything vertical out of your code.

Comment: see this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/suchit/u8htt9kr/1/

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should set DIV `height:100%;` to be like Semplice.
after that for set mouse position in center of element you should calculate DIV width and give it as half margin-left

```
var halfwidth = ($("#follow"))/2;
$("#follow").css('margin-left',halfwidth);
```

I hope I get the point right :)

Comment: This is actually pretty close to what I had in mind! But the issue I run into is if I set the width to 100% so it is responsive, how can I set the hover to go across the the whole width? I know it has something to do with the "limitX=150-15" in js. I just don't know how to add the width of the actual "container" class.

Here is what I tried to do: http://jsfiddle.net/663L0njt/1/